# Write the limit as a definite integral

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}n^{-3/2}=\int_0^1\sqrt{x}~\mathrm{d}x$$

What is the change in $x$ for the sum and why is the integral from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: The sum is just a Riemann sum, and so it turns into an integral when you take the limit

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}n^{-3/2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac kn}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riemann sum definition of the definite integral? If so that's all that's happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Riemann integral can be seen as a "limit process" and in particular, when the function has some nice regularity property, as the limit of a sum.

The global overview could be seen as this.

First, we start with staircase function, their integral is just the sum of the rectangle formed by their graph on a given interval.

Then for a function $f$ that satisfies some regularity conditions we like to consider two sets : one of the integral of the staircase functions that are below $f$ and one of the integral of the staircase functions that are above $f$.

Then, a famous theorem states that if the supremum of the first is equal to the infinimum of the second set then $f$ is Riemann integrable. (where the sup and the inf is taken over the set of partition of a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$)

Consider now we are on the interval $[a,b]$ with the partition $a=x_0 , ...., b=x_n$.

There is a simple way of having the integral of a staircase function above $f$ by considering the following sum (Upper Riemann sum) $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}sup_{\zeta_i\in[x_{i+1}, x_i]}f(\zeta_i)(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$ and the same applies for the integral of a staircase function below $f$ (lower Riemann sum) : $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}inf_{\zeta_i\in[x_{i+1}, x_i]}f(\zeta_i)(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$

Now consider the simpler case where we are not taking any supremum or infinimum, and the partition of the interval $[a,b]$ is very fair, that is $x_i = a+ i\frac{b-a}{n}$ clearly the distance between each $x_i$ is the same and we consider the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{b-a}{n}f\left(a+i\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$

Thus, we have this powerfull result for continuous function : $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{b-a}{n}f\left(a+i\frac{b-a}{n}\right) = \displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

This result relies the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition of the Riemann integrability and I don't know if you are familiar with it but it is something you can find  on the forum if you are curious.

Heuristically the idea is simple : the more the step of the subdivision tends to $0$, the more precise the calculation of the area under the curve is.

Now in you example you have $[a,b] = [0,1]$ so $x_i = \frac{i}{n}$ and $\frac{b-a}{n} = \frac{1}{n}$ and we deduce $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.

To see that the integral goes from $0$ to $1$ you need to remark that it is a Riemann sum of the function $\sqrt{x}$ (you don't have a lot of candidate in any case) and then you need to see that, with your notation, for $k=1$ you have $\frac{1}{n}$ and for $k=n$ you have $\frac{n}{n} = 1$.

I hope this help !